# Custom fonts not rendering on Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-chrome, firefox

Why my custom embedded fonts are not rendering on Firefox & IE. It does render on Chrome and on my local machine. I've properly embedded them

Please check below link with FF  & Chrome and you will see the difference: 
http://www.superiorbondcleaning.com.au/devsite/

I'm working on development site and I know there is redirect issue, all the links are redirecting to parent site. Can this be this reason?

Here is the `.httacess` rules which I can see in WordPress permalinks editor:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /devsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me why is not working in FF & IE but it is working in Chrome? Thanks.

Comment: its not the htaccess issue for fonts

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following error, when you open the Firefox error console:

`downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FuturaStd-CondensedLight" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: http://superiorbondcleaning.com.au/devsite/wp-content/themes/canvas-scb/includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedLight.ttf`.

In order to use the custom fonts, provide the absolute URL to them, not relative ones, as you do now.

Replace the URL in following lines with absolute ones (also for other fonts), then clear your browser cache and test again:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FuturaStd-CondensedBold';
    src: url('includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedBold.eot');
    src: url('includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedBold.woff') format('woff'), url('includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedBold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('includes/fonts/FuturaStd-CondensedBold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Comment: Would you please look at http://www.superiorbondcleaning.com.au/ Even I have changed it to absolute urls but it is still not working.Any idea? And I don't see any console error in FF.